# What does this expression a[b] represent in C#

Tags: c#

I have often seen this expression in a maintenance code

```
Global["Name"]
```

What does this represent? I have used `Global.Name` but never `Global["Name"]`?

Is there are a place where this type of expression is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used when looking up dictionaries and collections containing key/value pairs, eg.

```
var peopleAges = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>();
peopleAges["fred"] = 21;
peopleAges["emma"] = 18;

var fredAge = peopleAges["fred"];  // returns 21
```

Answer (score 8):

This is called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). In that case, `Global` is probably some kind of dictionary or hashtable. `"Name"` is a key to access a particular item in that dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It is a form of short hand allowed by C# called a default property. When an class has DefaultMemberAttribute set C# allows the name of the property named in that attribute to be omitted in that way.

Comment: Nope. It is only for indexers, you can't omit a property even if it is defined as the default member.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute "A property is imported as an indexer (default indexed property in Visual Basic) if the property has arguments and if the name of the property or one of its accessors matches the name specified by the DefaultMemberAttribute." C# does this transparently so that you don't have to define the attribute. I called it a default property since having used VB.NET in the distant past.